# How can I check the gameobject that the script is attached to in order to use the same script on multiple gameobjects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've just started learning to use Unity and so far I've managed to solve the problems I've encountered. I tried not to post, but I couldn't find what I was looking for.

In my game, I have a machine that changes the players' sprites. I wanted to use the same script for multiple machines. The idea was to detect the game object (machine) and change the sprite accordingly. For example, the script detects that it is a green machine and changes the sprites to green or detects that it is a red machine and changes the sprites to red.

I hope I made myself clear. I tend to overcomplicate things...

Comment: There are so many ways to do this.  Since you use the same script for each machine it is very straightforward.  Just add a color variable to each individual machine or assign a Sprite variable or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create something to distinguish between the different types of GameObjects. One way of doing this is to attach a script (monobehaviour) to each GameObject and give it a public variable for its colour. such as:

```
public string color;
```

You will see that this option will show up in the editor for any gameobject that has the script. Now you can give each object a different colour with the same script. You can now access it and use it to determine what happens.

```
if (color = "green") { }
```

To access it from a different script, get the object and use this:

```
x.GetComponent<TheNameOfYourScript>().color
```

If you need to get a reference to the GameObject a script is attached to (not the type, the specific one), you can use the term "gameObject" such as:

```
return gameObject;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the help. But I talked to a programmer friend who told me that it is best to keep sperated scripts, so that's what I'm going to do. Thanks again anyways.